# Error in showing user profile link in homepage in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    commented_on = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    commented_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    commented_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Blogger(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='bloggers')
    blogger_bio = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

URL.py for username

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.author_desc, name='author_desc'),
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, User, Comment, Blogger
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def home(request):    
    posts_list = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

and my home.html where i want to display:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>All Blogs</h2>

{% for post in posts %}
  <a href="{% url 'post_desc' pk=post.pk %}"><b>Post Topic: </b>{{ post.topic }}</br></a>
      <b>Published Time: </b>{{ post.created_on }}</br>
      <b>Author: </b><a href="{% url 'author_desc' blogger.username %}">{{ post.created_by }}</a></br></br>
{% endfor %}

</body>

</html>
```

I want to show each blogger's page from a link from the home. But it is getting problem.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal NoReverseMatch at /


Reverse for 'author_desc' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$']

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `blogger.username` parameter is empty.

Infact the models are not looking that good. The ForeignKey in the Post model should be to the `Blogger` model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Blogger, related_name='posts')
```

Then in the template you can do

```
{% for post in posts %}
 <a href="{% url 'post_desc' pk=post.pk %}"><b>Post Topic: </b>{{ post.topic }}</br></a>
  <b>Published Time: </b>{{ post.created_on }}</br>
  <b>Author: </b><a href="{% url 'author_desc' post.created_by.user.username %}">{{ post.created_by.user }}</a></br></br>{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actually i had a problem that whenever i was creating a user profile, it was not adding to blogger automatically. So, to solve that i used django signals(post_save) to create a signal between them. So, that whenever i create a new profile, it automatically also create blogger profile for it. So, do i need to change that to this or that signals are OKAY?

Comment: If you have a Profile model that will be enough no need for an extra Blogger model. Add blogger_bio field to your Profile model. Then in your Post model give ForeignKey to Profile. That is better.

Comment: There is no profile model. I just have Post, Comment, Blogger and User models.

Comment: Is it your signal that not working ? I think the question is not related to that.

Comment: Signals are working, but the profile link is having problem. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{% for post in posts %}
<a href="{% url 'post_desc' pk=post.pk %}"><b>Post Topic: </b>{{ post.topic }}</br></a>
  <b>Published Time: </b>{{ post.created_on }}</br>
  <b>Author: </b><a href="{% url 'author_desc' post.created_by.username %}">{{ post.created_by }}</a></br></br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In views.py, i added, blogger_list = Blogger.objects.all() and at last 'return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts, 'blogger_list': blogger_list})' and in template 'blogger_list.username'. Still not working.

Comment: Do you intend to show all the bloggers link from the home page? If yes you would have to use a loop in the template to show each bloggers link. 
And 'bloggers_list' is a list of bloggers, while 'blogger_object' is supposed to be a single blogger

Comment: How to use a for loop in {% url %}??